# Finding Location through IP address Nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to find the location of an IP address. The IP address will be sent to the API through a front end android/iOS application(I'm currently using a static IP address of my computer). I want to use the client IP address to then determine their, likely, physical location and send the location to MongoDB to be stored. Any help regarding this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can utilize [GeoIP-lite](https://github.com/bluesmoon/node-geoip) to get the geodata from the ip address.

```
var geoip = require('geoip-lite');

var ip = "207.97.227.239";
var geo = geoip.lookup(ip);

console.log(geo);
/*{ range: [ 3479297920, 3479301339 ],
  country: 'US',
  region: 'TX',
  city: 'San Antonio',
  ll: [ 29.4889, -98.3987 ],
  metro: 641,
  zip: 78218 }*/
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked for me. But can it give me a bit more specific location of the user?

Comment: @NoumanKhan Through GeoLocation, we can map IP address to the country, region, city, latitude/longitude, ISP, etc. All these information are collected and stored in the different database from different registrars. Some registrars may be very accurate in providing information about their IP, though some may enter not updated or incorrect data. So what kind of specific location you needed apart from this?

Comment: I was a little confused about something, clearified my confusion thank you @Ridham Tarpara

Answer (score 3):

> As of March 31 2018 the old freegeoip API is deprecated and a
> completely re-designed API is now accessible at
> http://api.ipstack.com. While the new API offers the same capabilities
> as the old one and also has the option of returning data in the legacy
> format, the API URL has now changed and all users are required to sign
> up for a free API Access Key to use the service.

[source](https://github.com/apilayer/freegeoip/#required-changes-to-legacy-integrations-freegeoipnetjsonxml)

---

You can use [freegeoip.net](https://freegeoip.net) :

```
freegeoip.net/{format}/{IP_or_hostname}
```

Sample GET http://freegeoip.net/json/207.97.227.239 :

```
{
  ip: "207.97.227.239",
  country_code: "US",
  country_name: "United States",
  region_code: "TX",
  region_name: "Texas",
  city: "San Antonio",
  zip_code: "78218",
  time_zone: "America/Chicago",
  latitude: 29.4889,
  longitude: -98.3987,
  metro_code: 641
}
```

Limitations :

> You're allowed up to 10,000 queries per hour by default. Once this limit is reached, all of your requests will result in HTTP 403, forbidden, until your quota is cleared.
>
> The freegeoip web server is free and open source so if the public service limit is a problem for you, download it and run your own instance.

---

If you only need country precision, you can use [cloudflare ip geoloc](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168236-What-does-Cloudflare-IP-Geolocation-do-), it ads an header to the request, so no extra API call.

Comment: FYI: I love Cloudflare but their geo service only gives country code.

Comment: It's actually a 100 request per month for freegeoip.net

Answer (score 1):

You can give the free IP2Location.io API a try. Just register for the free API key at https://www.ip2location.io/ and then use the Node.js code below to call the API:

```
var https = require("https");

const BASE_URL = "https://api.ip2location.io/";

let data = {
  key: "YOUR_API_KEY", // IP2Location.io API key
  ip: "8.8.8.8" // IP address to query
};

let url = BASE_URL + "?";

Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key, index) {
  if (this[key] != "") {
    url += key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(this[key]) + "&";
  }
}, data);

url = url.substring(0, url.length - 1);

let d = "";
let req = https.get(url, function (res) {
  res.on("data", (chunk) => (d = d + chunk));
  res.on("end", function () {
    console.log(JSON.parse(d));
  });
});
```

You should see the results like below:

```
{
  ip: '8.8.8.8',
  country_code: 'US',
  country_name: 'United States of America',
  region_name: 'California',
  city_name: 'Mountain View',
  latitude: 37.405992,
  longitude: -122.078515,
  zip_code: '94043',
  time_zone: '-07:00',
  asn: '15169',
  as: 'Google LLC',
  is_proxy: false
}
```