# Best way to detect locale for Stripe payments

Tags: stripe-payments, locale

I am currently using Stripe for my payments. I want to display different currencies depending on the locale. My approach is to check the locale and query the correct currency, is this the correct way of doing so? I am currently using Stripes ready checkout session.

If that is the correct approach, which is the best way to get locale?

1 - Detecting the browser language
[How can I get the browser language in node.js (express.js)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845471/how-can-i-get-the-browser-language-in-node-js-express-js)

2 - Using the IP address with a library
[Finding Location through IP address Nodejs mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49173287/finding-location-through-ip-address-nodejs-mongodb)

Comment: Which solution did you decide on in the end, and how did it work out?

Answer (score -1):

No, Stripe Checkout will do that for you. It will detect your customers' location and display appropriate PaymentMethods to increase the conversion. See https://stripe.com/payments/checkout

Comment: I would like to determine the locale in order to change the currency as I have to specify whats product/price the user is subscribing to on initial payment.